# TypeError: (options.astTransformers || []).map is not a function angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, angular-test, angular10

I have a unit test running using the

```
"jest": "^26.4.2",
"jest-preset-angular": "^8.3.1",
```

When I run the command `npm run test:app` it was working fine in Angular 8, now I have updated the angular to the latest version 10. I am getting an error as below on every test component

Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: (options.astTransformers || []).map is not a function

  at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:225:64)
  at ConfigSet.tsJest (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:43:24)
  at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:297:41)
  at ConfigSet.versions (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:43:24)
  at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:588:32)
  at ConfigSet.jsonValue (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:43:24)
  at ConfigSet.get [as cacheKey] (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:603:25)
  at TsJestTransformer.getCacheKey (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/ts-jest-transformer.js:126:36)
```

This is one of the component that is facing error

```
describe('DateSelectionComponent', () => {
      let component: DateSelectionComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<DateSelectionComponent>;
    
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [DateSelectionComponent, SafePipe],
          imports: [
            SharedModule,
            NgReduxTestingModule,
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
          ],
          providers: [
            {
              provide: PageAPIActions, useValue: { setPageState() { } }
            }
          ]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      }));
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DateSelectionComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        Object.defineProperties(component, {
          page$: {
            value: of('value'),
            writable: true
          },
          page: {
            value: { destination: 'value' },
            writable: true
          },
          startDate: {
            value: new NgbDate(2019, 2, 27),
            writable: true
          },
          minDate: {
            value: new NgbDate(2019, 2, 27),
            writable: true
          }
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    
      it('Should Match Snapshot', async () => {
        (expect(fixture) as any).toMatchSnapshot();
      });
    });
```

Jest configuration

**Jest.app config**

```
const baseConfig = require('./jest.base.config');

module.exports = {
    ...baseConfig,
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/dist'],
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/src/app/shared'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@pts-ngx/core": "<rootDir>/dist/pts-ngx/core",
        "^@pts-ngx/core/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/dist/pts-ngx/core/$1",
        'projects/pts-ngx/core/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/projects/pts-ngx/core/$1'
    }
};
```

**Jest base config**

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupJest.ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@pts-ngx/core": "<rootDir>/dist/pts-ngx/core",
        "^@pts-ngx/core/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/dist/pts-ngx/core/$1"
    }
};
```

**Jest.library config**

```
// jest.lib.config.js
const baseConfig = require('./jest.base.config');

module.exports = {
    ...baseConfig,
    roots: ['<rootDir>/projects'],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This help me,

1. Uninstall jest-preset-angular
2. Reinstall jest-preset-angular
3. Clear jest cache
4. Retry

To clean the cache on angular.json file add the below script

```
"scripts": {
"clear_jest": "jest --clearCache"
  }
```

Then run `npm run clear_jest`

If the above option doesn't work try explicitly install ts-jest by `npm install --dev ts-jest`

This error mainly occurs due to the wrong version of `ts-jest` in package.json.lock file.

Answer (score 0):

try to update "ts-jest" to latest version (26.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

running **npm install --dev ts-jest** resolved my issue.